# UITableViewController custom cell scrolling performance

Tags: iphone, uitableview

So I have a UITableViewController. The cells in this tableview have the following UIControls:

```
 2 UILabels, one of which has a shadow and a clearColor background color.
 1 Custom Progress view resized to be larger and with a different color
 3 UIButtons
```

Functionally, they do exactly what they are supposed to do. However, I've noticed when looking at it on device that scrolling performance quickly tanks and has dropped frames all over the place, even with other interactions like pushing one of the buttons.

So I was reading around today and found http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/ this article by the Tweetie guy about how to achieve fast scrolling performance by subclassing UITableViewCell and doing the drawing yourself.

The example works extremely well, but when I tried to adapt it to work with my desired configuration I realized that he isn't using any predefined UI Controls, he's mapping out everything by hand.

While I can see how this would be an extremely efficient way to do things, it strikes me as problematic for things like the progress view and the buttons, and even one of my labels to a certain extent.

So my question is this: Do I need to completely write my controls from scratch if I want my scrolling performance to be good, or is there a way to use the standard UI Controls and get good scrolling performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding custom controls to your cell, you should still be subclassing UITableViewCell, adding your controls in the init function, laying them out in layoutSubviews, etc. - just like any other view.  As VdesmedT says, make sure you're re-using cells via the dequeue mechanism, so that you aren't allocating new cells with each scrolling operation.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Currently all the controls are being allocated in `cellForRoWAtIndexPath` which means every time it grabs a reusable cell it's allocating a bunch of labels and shoving them in there, instead of just setting the data those controls should display. I'll give it a whirl tonight and see if that helps my scroll performance.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I will propose something obvious but to achieve UIScrollView performance, you need to be sure that the dequeue mechanism works well.  I often see developers not properly set the identifier in IB and therefore missing the UITableViewCell cache benefit

Comment: As of right now I'm not using IB at all for the cell. I'm using the default cell identifier and adding the controls as subviews and manually positioning them.

Comment: @DVG : Manually position them at creation, not after you dequeue a cell right ?